# Match multiple instances using RegExp and store values (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I would like to match all values with this pattern: `@[\S]+`. This will be used to get all names after an `@` in a comment. Example:

`Here are some people: @Name1, @Name2, @Name3, @Name4`

should return: `["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"]`

I have tried to use `comment.match(/@[\S]+/ig)` but this returns an array with the `@` symbol. I have tried to encapsulate the pattern with brackets: `comment.match(/@([\S]+)/ig)` but this doesn't help either. There may be more than 10 names that are matched so RegExp can't be used, and I'd rather not have to iterate through the array and strip it out.

Help appreciated :) .

Comment: What do You mean by RegExp can't be used?

Comment: I meant `RegExp.$x`.

Answer (score 1):

Use positive look behind

```
 /(?<=@)\S+/
```

/Edit
I've read that JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds. So I recommend using:

```
result.map(function(a) {a.slice(1)})
```

On each

Comment: This seems to give a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=@)\S+/: Invalid group` when running the following:

`"@Name1, and @Name2".match(/(?<=@)\S+/ig);`

Comment: I've just read that Javascript regexp doesn't support lookbehinds. No way to do it then

Comment: @KrzysztofWende: sure you can, using capture groups.

Comment: @KrzysztofWende: and furthermore you probably better replace `\S` with `\w`, otherwise the comma (`,`) is captured as well.

Comment: @CommuSoft yeah. I trusted OP too much ;)

Comment: Unfortunately `,` is an acceptable username character. `\S` is therefore required, but I realise it will match trailing `,`, but I can't think of any way around it.

Comment: "Oxford,coma,for,the,win"  best username ever

Comment: @KeirSimmons to be honest, I don't know any application that allows commas. Twitter only allows letters, numbers and underscores. [source](http://kagan.mactane.org/blog/2009/09/22/what-characters-are-allowed-in-twitter-usernames/).

Comment: It's a relatively popular forum system, ZetaBoards.

Answer (score 1):

As @KrzysztofWende you can use a *look behind* approach, or you can use capture groups:

With the regex:

```
/@(\w+)/ig
```

I replaced `\S` with `\w`, since otherwise the comma (`,`) is matched with `Name1` as well.

Then the code reads:

```
var myString = "Here are some people: @Name1, @Name2, @Name3, @Name4";
var myRegexp = /@(\w+)/ig;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);//do something useful with match[1]
```

Or in case you need to iterate over all possible matches:

```
var myString = "Here are some people: @Name1, @Name2, @Name3, @Name4";
var myRegexp = /@(\w+)/ig;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
    alert(match[1]);
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

The solution makes use of *capture groups*: it numbers brackets starting from `1` (`0` is the total match). In this case group `1` is thus `(\w+)`.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kommusoft/nzu8thkw/).